# Extending TabControl and TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

I am just trying out extending TabControl and TabItem for fun; including providing custom styles. I am creating the ExTabControl programatically, and adding several ExTabItem(myDataObject) to the tabcontrol. myDataObject has several properties, like "Title" and "Editor." Editor is of type UIElement.

What I am struggling with is how do I bind the Editor property to be the tab panel's content?

Comment: have you got some sample code for us? its alittle hard to follow without seeing what you have so far..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind the tab item's content property to a control or another property.